# Finding a value in a set with rails and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, set, capybara

I'm trying to solve what is most likely a quick problem...

I have this so far

```
page.check 'Vendor'
page.check 'Partner'
click_button 'Invite'

newUser = User.find_by_email("lemmy@dl.com")

puts "ROLES"
puts newUser.roles
puts "ROLES"

expect(newUser.roles).to have_content("partner")
expect(newUser.roles).to have_content("vendor")
```

and what this outputs is :

```
ROLES
admin
vendor
partner
ROLES
```

and then an error:
 `expected to find text "partner" in "#"`

I was wondering why this is, and although I know that the partner value is there since I printed it, I would like a way to automatically check it so i can get rid of those puts.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have_content` looks at the web page to see if it has the content but you are inspecting `newUser.roles` instead.  If `newUser.roles` returns an array use the `include` matcher instead:

```
expect(newUser.roles).to include("partner")
expect(newUser.roles).to include("vendor")
```